# Move MovieClip and everything it contains

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I have a MovieClip called navbar and it has buttons over it. How do I connect the buttons to the MovieClip so that when the MovieClip is moved the buttons move with it? I have been able to make the navbar draggable but the buttons aren't dragged with it.

I have tried the following:

```
navbar.addChild(button1);
```

This just made the button disappear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach is correct: adding the buttons as children to the MovieClip will allow them all to be moved as one item.

The button disappearing could be any number of reasons, for instance x and y now relative to new parent (i.e. setting button y to 600 is now 600 pixels down from the navbar, not from the stage or old parent).

Try commenting out any properties you have set on the button and see if that resolves the issue, from there you can determine which property is causing the button to disappear.

So you should basically just have something like this:

```
var button1:Button = new Button();
navbar.addChild(button1);
```

If even with that minimal code doesn't result in the button displaying on the navbar, you'll need to post more code so that we can see where the problem is occurring.

Answer (score 1):

As you supposed, if you want the `navbar` and the buttons to act like a unique element you need to put buttons inside the `navbar` and not just over it.

The reason the button is disappearing is due to the fact that it has been put on the stage in Designer so, when you add it to `navbar`, you have it into two different display stacks, and that's not allowed.

You should put buttons inside the `navbar` in Designer, or export them for AS and then instance them dynamically, as follow:

```
var btn:Button1 = new Button1()
navbar.addChild(btn)
```

Class name `Button1` is assigned in the *MovieClip properties* window of the Library, under *Export for ActionScript*.

Comment: Can you explain how I put buttons inside `navbar` in Designer?

Comment: just double click on a navbar instance on the stage (or in the library). You begin the MovieClip edit mode, now just add your buttons to navbar.

Answer (score 1):

you can calculate distance from Movieclip's X,Y to buttons and you can write a code like this:

```
var diff1:int = navbar.x - example_button1.x;
    stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, function(event:Event):void{
example_button1.x=navbar.x-diff1;
    });
```

you can duplicate example_buttons and diff variables.

or you can `startDrag()` sametime with same event listener,

```
navbar.addEventListener(someEvent.some, function(event:someEvent):void{
MovieClip(root).navbar.startDrag();
MovieClip(root).example_button1.startDrag();
});
```

`MovieClip(root)` allows you to effect main stage. With this property you can effect an object from inside of navbar for example.